# how to use database digitalOcean with my xampp

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp, digital-ocean

** how to use dbDigitalOcean on my local sql xampp mac ? **
** i try to add in xampp->xamppfiles->phpmyadmin->config.inc.php  but it not works ** 
please help

[image]

Comment: create a new server in phpmyadmin using the specifications provided. Localhost is the phpmyadmin machine. You want ALL of the details from the dbDigitalOcean page in the connection, including the CA certificate.

Comment: do you have example for how to do it  sir .

Comment: Nope, but if you want to read the [documentation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#server-connection-settings) it may help you out.  In fact it might be very similar to the [google cloud example](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#example-google-ssl) with different connection details.

Answer (score 0):

You should almost certainly not expose your MySQL (usually port 3306, but perhaps port 25060 in your pasted image) directly to the internet. You can install phpMyAdmin to your server at Digital Ocean, use your web server or other means to secure it to your level of comfort, and access the database through the phpMyAdmin that’s installed on your server. This will be more efficient and probably more secure than directly putting the MySQL server on the internet. You won’t connect to your local XAMPP or local phpMyAdmin at all in this case, since it will all be on the server.